# Change TableView's content on click of view's menu

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, tableview

I have a new impossibile problem while I'm developing an Eclipse's plugin.

I need to populate a TableView and insert it into a Eclipse's View. I could do it, but my plugin need to change the content of tableview on menu click.

In particular, I need to refresh the tableview with new data.

Since now, this is my code:

```html
public void createPartControl( Composite parent ) 
{
 CustomAction lCustomAction = new CustomAction( parent , 1 , this);  
 
 lCustomAction.setText("Load content with index 1");
 lCustomAction.setImageDescriptor(Activator.getImageDescriptor("icons/sample.gif"));  
 getViewSite().getActionBars().getMenuManager().add(lCustomAction);
 
 GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(2, false);
 parent.setLayout(layout);   
 
 Thread t = new Thread( new RunSMV());
 t.start();
}
public class CustomAction extends Action implements IWorkbenchAction
{
 private Composite parent;
 private int index;
 SampleView sv;
 public CustomAction(Composite parent, int index, SampleView sv)
 {
  setId(ID);
  this.parent = parent;
  this.index = index;
  this.sv = sv; 
 }

 public void run() 
 {
  try
  {      
   sv.createViewer(parent, index);   
  } catch (IOException | ParserConfigurationException | SAXException e) {
   
   e.printStackTrace();
  }  
 }
 public void dispose() {} 
}
public void createViewer(Composite parent, int index) throws IOException, ParserConfigurationException, SAXException
{
 ArrayList<ArrayList<CounterExample>> listAll = RunNuSMV.RunNuSMV();
 ArrayList<CounterExample> list = listAll.get(index);
 int numeroColonne = list.get(1).getN();
 
 viewer = new TableViewer( parent , SWT.MULTI | SWT.H_SCROLL
   | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.FULL_SELECTION | SWT.BORDER);
   
 createColumns( numeroColonne , parent , viewer);
 final Table table = viewer.getTable(); 
 table.setLinesVisible(true);
 viewer.setContentProvider(new ArrayContentProvider());
 TableColumn column[] = new TableColumn[numeroColonne];
 for(int k=0;k < numeroColonne;k++ )
 {
   column[k] = new TableColumn(table, SWT.NONE);
 }
     
 CounterExample oldRow = list.get(0);
 CounterExample row;
 
 for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) 
 {
  row = list.get(i);  
  TableItem item1 = new TableItem(table, SWT.NONE);
  item1.setText(row.getRow());
  
  for(int j=0; j < numeroColonne;j++)
  {
   if(j != 0 && i >= 2 && row.getVar(j).equals(oldRow.getVar(j))==false )
   {
    Display disp = Display.getCurrent();
    Color yellow = disp.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_YELLOW);
    item1.setBackground( j , yellow );
   }
  }  
  oldRow = row;     
 }

 for(int k=0;k<numeroColonne;k++)
 {
  column[k].pack();
 }
 
 getSite().setSelectionProvider(viewer);
 GridData gridData = new GridData();
 
 gridData.verticalAlignment = GridData.FILL;       
 gridData.horizontalSpan = 2;
 gridData.grabExcessHorizontalSpace = true;
 gridData.grabExcessVerticalSpace = true;
 gridData.horizontalAlignment = GridData.FILL;
 
 viewer.getControl().setLayoutData(gridData);
}
```

As you can imagine, if I call the method createView() into the run() method of CustomAction, the program will show nothing.

I've tried also to understand when the CustomAction menu is clicked , and then call createView() inside CreatePartControl(), but I couldn't catch the event.

Finally I couldn't refresh the viewpart, in fact if I insert createview() in a cycle in the view will add multiple tableviews.

You can see it in this image: https://goo.gl/fT0BGp

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you use `TableViewer` you should be using a content provider and label provider and **not** using `TableItem`. See http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseJFaceTable/article.html

Comment: @greg-449 I had to use TableItem for coloring the background of a cell instead of Content provider. Do you think this can create problems with other functions ?

Comment: The Label Provider using IColorProvider can do that or use Column Viewers. Mixing TableViewer and TableItem is a very bad idea.

Comment: Hello @greg-449, I have done what you suggest to me! It's work perfectly. Now to refresh the content I only need to call setInput method. Thanks you!